# Strange behavior with bash for loop

Tags: bash, shell

I have this small script:

```
#!/bin/bash

output=`find "/home/tran/myfolder" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d`
for folder in "$output"
do
    echo "This is $folder"
    echo "$folder exist"
done
```

The result is:

```
This is /home/tran/myfolder/folder1
/home/tran/myfolder/folder2
/home/tran/myfolder/folder3
/home/tran/myfolder/folder1
/home/tran/myfolder/folder2
/home/tran/myfolder/folder3 exist
```

Can you explain me why the loop behaves like that ? Any reply is appreciated.

Comment: You have saved output as a string and then loop over the single string since you have quoted it. You could just unquote the var, but then this would open up to problems with special characters expanding. You should save it to an array `output=($(command))` and loop over the elements using `for folder in "${output[@]}"`

Comment: Creating an array from an unquoted command substitution is no safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have `"` (double quote) around `$output`, it is processed as one string

Comment: @TranNguDang Please don't just unquote the var, you will run into trouble later. You should use an array.

Comment: @123 You are right, I ll follow your advice above. Too bad can't mark your answer as correct

Comment: @TranNguDang You can always add one yourself! I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate though which is why I didn't add an answer.

Comment: It's as @123 said. Depending on what you have to put in the loop, you could use an `exec` on the find command or pipe the output to `xargs`. You can for sure use bash array too

Answer (score 3):

[Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) covers the correct way to iterate over the output of a command line by line. However, unless you know something about the results before hand, there is no guarantee that the output of `find` produces one file per line, because a newline is a valid filename character.

In your case, you don't need `find`; iterating over a filename pattern will produce the result your want:

```
for folder in /home/tran/myfolder/*/; do
    echo "$folder"
done
```

Comment: Thanks. This is probably the best solution for my case

Answer (score 2):

**Never** iterate over filenames with a `for in` loop. That's because filenames on UNIX may contain spaces and if they do, the `for in` loop will break: Let's say you have a file called `head tail.txt`. In that case the loop would iterate over `head` and `tail.txt`.

You could use `find` directly to achieve the desired result:

```
find PATH -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf "This is %f\nfolder exists\n"
```

You could also use a glob expression like [chepner explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44284775/171318). Iterating over the results of a glob expression is safe because the results of the glob won't be subject to word splitting.

Comment: Note `printf` isn't available on BSD find like on mac.

Comment: Use GNU/Linux! ;) (Thanks for letting me know)